# Java Sound MidiInDevice Thread is never closing

Tags: java, multithreading, midi

when I open a Midi IN device in Java and close it, my program will never terminate because the Java Sound MidiInDevice Thread never terminates. I could call System.exit(0) but I would like to avoid that.

Any ideas?

```
public class MidiClose {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MidiDevice.Info[] midiInfos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
        MidiDevice device = null;
        String midiDeviceName = "Bus 1";

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < midiInfos.length; i++) {
                if (midiInfos[i].getName().equals(midiDeviceName)) {
                    device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(midiInfos[i]);

                    if (device.getMaxTransmitters() != 0) {
                        device.open();
                        device.close();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all you dont print anything in catch  so how do you know what's happening you must be a magician - second of all all exceptions are not caught so there you go

Comment: Yeah you are totally right, I just chopped all exception handling to the minimum to provide the most readable code. Pure magic...

Comment: I have the exact same issue with JDK 1.8.0_131 on OS X. It occurs only for some of the MIDI input devices, not all. And only input devices. It always works fine with output devices...